# Difficulty binding mvc model to JSON post

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following JSON Request body (copied from ie10 Admin Panel Network capture)

```
{"FirstName":"James","LastName":"Jones","Email":"jJones@system.net"}
```

My controller is as follows (the x variable is to break on):

```
[HttpPost]
public void EditPerson(PersonUpdateViewModel person)
{
    int x = 0;
}
```

My ViewModel is as follows:

```
public class PersonUpdateViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The EditPerson Action is reached, I break on the x variable, but all of the properties in the person variable are null, does anyone have any hints for what I might be doing wrong? At this point I would even be ok accepting the raw JSON string and parsing from there but I can't get any parameter into the action method.

javascript function I am posting from by request:

```
var submitEdit2 = function () {
    var editables = $('.editable')
    var person = new Object();
    for (var i = 0; i < editables.length; i++) {
        var editable = editables[i];
        person[editable.name] = editable.value;
    }
    var jform = JSON.stringify(person);
    $.post('/Person/EditPerson', jform, null, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code from where you are posting the parameter "person"?

Comment: You mean the javascript?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Html.BeginFormAjax()` or so? What js does it generate?

Comment: I am not sure how to use Html.BeginFormAjax() and would prefer to not be locked into a form anyways. Eventually I will be using a foreach loop to generate a variable number of inputs and need to package the results of those inputs into an array.

Comment: Does your person object have the same properties as the personupdatemodel class?

Comment: @BhushanFirake the JSON string is listed first, I believe from looking at it the person object is being produced correctly. I'm a little confused why everyone keeps focusing on the javascript. Is there something wrong with the JSON that is being sent that leads people to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an AJAX post and specifying the
contentType to 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

```
     $.ajax( {
     type: "POST",
     url: /Person/EditPerson',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: jform
     }
```

If this does not solve the issue please post the header information.  I am guessing that using the $post is sending "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" data which .NET MVC does not like.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/